# How to specify in a python function that a passed argument must be a function

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, arguments, type-hinting

I've made a function that takes a function as an argument.

If I want to specify that a function takes an integer it's pretty easy:

```
def fun(myInt:int=0):
    return myInt
```

But when it takes a function I can't do this:

```
def fun(myFun:function=print):
    myFun('whatever')
```

I printed type() of both an integer and a function and got
`<class 'int'>
<class 'function'>`

What is the difference between these two and is an easy way to do what I wanted to do?

Btw. I've already used fellow google and couldn't find anything

Comment: You are using *type hinting* and the correct spelling would be to use a [`typing.Callable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Callable) generic.

Comment: Alrighty then, thanks a lot!
(Looks like what I needed was to know the name of what I was looking for)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python 3:

```
from typing import Callable

def fun(myFun:Callable=print):
    myFun('whatever')

fun()
fun(print)
fun(type)
```